# Formatting Sweet Alert text without html: tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make changes to Sweet Alert `title:` and `text:` texts. But since `html:` is discontinued in the newer versions of SweetAlert, I want to know how to achieve it.

Here is the format that I want the text in -

```
In the title-
Line 1 //line break here 
Line 2 //line break here
Line 3 //line break here
Line 4 //line break here

In the text-

Line 5 //line break here 
Line 6 //line break here
Line 7 //line break here
Line 8 //lie break here
```

Here is my code

**HTML page**

```
 var name = $('#ade_name').val();
             var email = $('#ade_email').val();
             var role = $('#ade_role').val();
             var notf = $('#ade_notf').val();
             var emver = $('#email_verified').val();
             var msg1= "You are going to make the following changes for: ";

              msg1+= " Name= ";
              msg1+= '\t'
             msg1+= name;
             msg1+= '\n\n';
             msg1+= " Email = ";
             msg1+= '\t'
             msg1+=email;
            msg1+= '\n\n';
              msg1+= " Please Double Confirm the details below to continue";
              var msg2 = "Role : ";
              msg2+= $('#ade_role').val();
               msg2+= '\n';
              msg2+= " Mark All Notifications as Unread ? : ";
              msg2+= $('#ade_notf').val();
               msg2+= '\n';
              msg2+= " Mark email as verified? : ";
              msg2+= $('#ade_email_verified').val();
              msg2+= '\n';
              swal({
                 
                  title: msg1,
                  text: msg2,
                  icon: "info",
                  buttons: true,
                  dangerMode: true,
                });
```

I am **not** getting line breaks using `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like line breaks are supported in the alert title (it's supposed to be a title, not an essay).

They are supported in the alert body. Re-organize your alert:

```js
$("#alert").click(function () {
    swal({
        title: "Please double-check before continuing",
        text: [
            " Name: " + $('#ade_name').val(),
            " Email: " + $('#ade_email').val(),
            " Role: " + $('#ade_role').val(),
            " Mark All Notifications as Unread? " + $('#ade_notf').is(":checked"),
            " Mark email as verified? " + $('#ade_email_verified').is(":checked")
        ].join("\n"),
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

Name: <input id="ade_name" value="user name"><br>
Email: <input id="ade_email" value="user email"><br>
Role: <input id="ade_role" value="user role"><br>
<input id="ade_notf" type="checkbox"> Mark All Notifications as Unread<br>
<input id="ade_email_verified" type="checkbox"> Mark email as verified<br>
<button id="alert">Show</button>
```